# Quartz cron expression for Once in a two week on particular day

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to create the Quartz cron expression which runs on every 2 week on given day

e.g.

Once in a every two week on Monday

and using the following expression

```
0 0 6 ? * 1#2,1#4
```

but somehow I am getting following error

> Support for specifying multiple "nth" days is not implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something that is also very hard with the regular cron jobs, I think it cannot be achieved in a 'normal' cron expression.

You could skip cron altogether and use the 
[Trigger That Executes Every 2 Weeks](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/BiWeeklyTrigger.html)

```
trigger = newTrigger()
.withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
.startAt(tomorrowAt(15, 0, 0)  // 15:00:00 tomorrow
.withSchedule(calendarIntervalSchedule()
        .withIntervalInWeeks(2)) // interval is set in calendar weeks
.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of cron-like expressions. The best solution that comes to my mind is to create two triggers for that job, instead of trying to use it only with the cron expression.

Comment: This is not a limitation of quartz since one could express such behaviour very easy with [SimpleTriggers](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/previous_versions/1.8.5/org/quartz/SimpleTrigger.html) (see [TriggerBuilder](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/TriggerBuilder.html)) - as @RobAu  mentioned. This is more a kind of shortcome of cron-like expressions in general.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I meant a limitation of Cron expressions, going to edit that now.