# Scheduling a job weekly with intervals

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I want to schedule a job using Quartz Scheduler which will occur weekly but with some intervals.
For example let say I want to schedule a job which will occur only on Friday and  Saturday but in a gap of 2 intervals. Meaning the next occurrence will not execute on next Friday and Saturday but on next to next Friday and Saturday.
Please tell me if you need any information.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quartz cron expression for Once in a two week on particular day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641783/quartz-cron-expression-for-once-in-a-two-week-on-particular-day)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html

Particularly this:

> 0 15 10 ? * 6#3   Fire at 10:15am on the third Friday of every month

I didn't see a way to have the same job fire on say the first and third Friday.
To get around this you can probably schedule multiple jobs. Example, one job to run on the first Friday, the second on the third Friday and so on...